# PL/PGSQL Dynamic Where

Tags: postgresql

I need to generate a dynamic Where into a PL/PGSQL function, for example:
I have this string

> hello, postgresql, stackoverflow

I need to do this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE tbl_col LIKE %hello% OR tbl_col LIKE %postgresql% OR tbl_col LIKE %stackoverflow%;
```

There's any way to split a string by comma and generate the dynamic where query?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`any(array[...])`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN20944):

```
select * 
from tblname 
where tbl_col like any(array['%hello%', '%postgresql%', '%stackoverflow%']);
```

Comment: Works fine, but only when I need a query with OR operator, how I can make it work when I need to use AND operator? Thanks you

Comment: Use `all(array[...])` instead of `any(array[...])` to get a conjunction.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SIMILAR TO operator instead of LIKE. you can find the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html)

an example:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tblname
WHERE
    tbl_col SIMILAR TO '%(' || REPLACE( 'hello,postgresql,stackoverflow', ',', '|' )|| ')%'
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working.. Another question, if I want to use AND operator instead OR? what function i need to use? Thanks again